# enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: can I be sure it is called on the same thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsdictionary

Lately I am using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` and today I have hesitated when one of my colleague at work place pointed out that this enumeration method can be called from separate thread and my code may not work as expected. He even suggested I should use fast enumeration. Problem is I really like `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` and dislike fast enumeration due to its nature when it comes to dictionary.

my method looked as following

```
- (NSArray *)someMethod
{
    __block NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.myDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [myArray addObject:obj];
    }

    return myArray;
}
```

Can I be sure that myArray will always return the expected values (assuming `self.myDictionary` is not empty) and it will be always called on the same thread as the someMethod?

I am aware there is a method `enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` and calling it with `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option will run enumeration simultaneously on multiple threads.

But I can't find any documentation regarding `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock`.
The same refers to `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` used on array.

Comment: What about fast enumeration's 'nature' do you dislike so strongly that you would rather use this method that you're unsure about?

Comment: Does the order matter here how you store things in your array within this block?

Comment: By the "nature" I mean calling allKeys enumerating them and then accessing the object, while with block enumeration you avoid that. Block - more convenient, easier code and perhaps less writing on my end.

Comment: @Unheilig, no it doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you observe, unless you call [`enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-SW18) with the [`NSEnumerationConcurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW193) option, you can be assured that they won't be performed concurrently. As to whether the non-concurrent rendition of `enumerateKeysAndObjects` runs on the same thread or not (though, I'd wager it does), it doesn't really matter if it didn't run on the same queue because this is run synchronously with respect to the thread that you called the enumeration method. Bottom line, your coworker's thread-related concerns are without merit.

I would note, though, that in my anecdotal testing, these enumeration methods are slower than fast enumeration. If speed is of paramount interest (e.g. especially if using huge dictionaries/arrays), then you might want to employ fast enumeration. In most scenarios, though, the difference is not material.

Comment: I agree with what @Rob said. I'd want to add that `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` actually calls `enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` internally passing `0` as `options` parameter.

Comment: @Hejazi How did you find out / know? Please elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig I found out by checking the call stack and registers when the block is executed.

Comment: @Hejazi I see, it somehow sounds to me like calling "the designated constructor" kind of thing, hence my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes, exactly. It's kind of a rule of thumb. No code is rewritten, and all overloaded (or convenience) versions of a method eventually call one method (mostly the one with most number of parameters).